# Functioning of IR-Photodiodes

Tags: resistors, resistance, infrared, photodiode

Do infrared photodiodes vary their resistance according to the strength of infrared radiation they receive? Or do they simply have some sort of HIGH and LOW state, meaning that they either let current pass or not.

Comment: Simple photo-diodes are not light activated switches. However their actual operation is more complicated and dependent on how you connect them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode

Comment: Do you understand an ordinary diode? A photodiode isn't much different. (An ordinary diode exposed to light becomes a photodiode, although perhaps not as effective).

Comment: I sense some X-Y problem here. What is your original, real problem with IR receivers?

Answer (score 1):

Exposing a photodiode to light shifts its I-V curve:

[image]

(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode))

When the applied bias on the diode is zero or negative (i.e. the cathode is biased higher than the anode), this makes the diode operate approximately as a current source, with output proportional to the incident optical power. The shunt conductance of this current source is fairly low, and does not depend strongly on the optical power.